# How to detect rectangle and straighten it with Pillow, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

[image]    [image]

I have the image on the left as an input.

Is there a straightfoward way to use Pillow in Python to recognise the rectangle's corners and rotate the image by the number of degrees necessary to have the edge of the rectangle parallel with the global axis - as show by the image on the right?